# Can we use Android kotlin Video player with react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to display a video player and contols it in react native but that video player is in kotlin language, So how can control and display android native activity and controls it in react native ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make a Video Player from native side, and expose via NativeModules and pass some props.

Ive done it a long time back and its possible, you can pass URL, height width etc . but im not sure about how well can you fetch the controls etc.

Check this article out, hope it helps : [Rn native ui comp](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#imageview-example)

Fee lfree for doubts

Comment: I need also to  access video player functions like onpause, onplay etc which is in native so is it also possible?

Comment: yes, those simple ones are possible as native modules., i strongly recommend you to check https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android this

Comment: i have to run this daily motion player from react native and controls it also from react native please check the below link. https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#embed-mobile-android-how-to

Comment: yes its possible, but if youre. not a native android developer, i suggest take a help in how to integrate it with RN

Comment: glad it helped, if you think it helped, do kindly upvote and mark as accepted. much appreciated